# findstr 2 arguments and 2 events

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I create a XML file from PRTG status monitor. in this XML file are values >4< for warning and >5< for error.

With `findstr` and `if errorlevel` I can only check if one of the value is true or false, but I want to check both values.

the goal to achieve is:

- when only >4< is in XML file, a serial string "warning_found" is sent to COM port.
- when only >5< is in XML file, a serial string "error_found" is sent to COM port.
- when >4< and >5< is in XML file, a serial string "error_found" is sent to COM port.
- when none of the 2 values are in XML file, a serial string "noerrord" is sent to COM port.

At the moment i have a functional batch file for only 2 variables => error and noerror (see below) but I want to implement the warning parameter as well:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
del %temp%\tmp.xml>nul 2>&1

::Init Variables
set url="http://127.0.0.1/api/table.xml"
set parameter="content=sensors&columns=status&username=wey&passhash=3085906047"
set com=COM3
set baud=9600
set parity=n
set data=8

::Read XML
curl.exe --data %parameter% %url% > %temp%\tmp.xml

::Init COM Port
mode %com% BAUD=%baud% PARITY=%parity% DATA=%data%

::Check for errors in xml
findstr /C:">5<" %temp%\tmp.xml
if errorlevel 1 goto noerror
goto error

:error
echo Error found
echo %* > %com%
echo fehler > %com%
goto end

:noerror
echo No error found
echo behoben > %com%
goto end

:end
del %temp%\tmp.xml>nul 2>&1
endlocal 
exit
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <sensors totalcount="528" listend="0">
   <prtg-version>19.2.50.2842</prtg-version>
   </item>
   <item>
    <status>OK </status>
    <status_raw>3</status_raw>
   </item>
   <item>
    <status>OK </status>
    <status_raw>3</status_raw>
   </item>
   <item>
    <status>OK </status>
    <status_raw>3</status_raw>
   </item>
   <item>
    <status>OK </status>
    <status_raw>3</status_raw>
   </item>
   <item>
    <status>Fehler </status>
    <status_raw>5</status_raw>
   </item>
   <item>
    <status>Fehler </status>
    <status_raw>5</status_raw>
   </item>
   <item>
    <status>Pausiert (Pausiert durch überg. Objekt)</status>
    <status_raw>7</status_raw>
   </item>
   <item>
    <status>Pausiert (pausiert)</status>
    <status_raw>7</status_raw>
   </item>
   <item>
    <status>Pausiert (Pausiert durch überg. Objekt)</status>
    <status_raw>7</status_raw>
   </item>
   <item>
    <status>Pausiert (Pausiert durch überg. Objekt)</status>
    <status_raw>7</status_raw>
   </item>
   <item>
    <status>Pausiert (pausiert)</status>
    <status_raw>7</status_raw>
   </item>
  </sensors>
```

Comment: Please [edit] and include the text.xml file (formatted as code)

Comment: A part of the XML file is attached. Warning value would be <4>.

Comment: Try to remove the /C: and just put `">4< >5<"` should work as an OR command if either is found. I think that's what you want, right? But you also need to escape the `>` and `<` characters so findstr `"^>4^< ^>5^<"`. Maybe use `find` command instead because it doesn't require you to escape all those characters and works remarkably well and similar to findstr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
del %temp%\tmp.xml>nul 2>&1

::Init Variables
set url="http://127.0.0.1/api/table.xml"
set parameter="content=sensors&columns=status&username=wey&passhash=3085906047"
set com=COM3
set baud=9600
set parity=n
set data=8

::Read XML
curl.exe --data %parameter% %url% >%temp%\tmp.xml

::Init COM Port
mode %com% BAUD=%baud% PARITY=%parity% DATA=%data%

2>nul findstr "\<4\>" "%tmp%\tmp.xml" >nul && (
2>nul findstr "\<5\>" "%tmp%\tmp.xml" >nul && (
goto error ) || goto warning ) || goto noerror

:noerror
echo=No error found: 4 and 5 not found
echo=behoben > %com%
goto end

:error
echo=Error found: 4 and 5 was found
echo=%* > %com%
echo=fehler > %com%
goto end

:warning
echo=Warning: only 4 was found
echo=behoben > %com%
goto end

:end
2>nul del /q /f %tmp%\tmp.xml >nul
endlocal 
exit
```

You can use `findstr` to search for `>4<`, and together the `&&` operator for when found, also `>5<` goes to `:error`, and operator `||` when not found, goes to `:warning`, because only `>4<` was found.

- This will handle the occurrences:

```bat
case: >4< only goto warning
case: >5< only goto error
case: >4< & >5< both goto error
```

- For cases where neither `>4<` nor `>5<` are found, then none of the `goto's` were executed, then `goto noerror`:

```bat
goto :error ) || goto :warning ) || goto noerror
```

---

- For cases where the next line/command is also the next statement, you can remove it, and it will be executed in the same way:

```bat
goto :error ) || goto :warning )  || goto noerror 

:noerror
echo=No error found: 4 and 5 not found
echo=behoben > %com%
goto end

:warning
echo=Warning: only 4 was found
echo=behoben > %com%
goto end

:end
2>nul del /q /f %tmp%\tmp.xml >nul
endlocal 
exit
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for the solution. I managed to achieve the same goal but not that elegantly as you did.

```
 @echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
del %temp%\tmp.xml>nul 2>&1

::Init Variables
set url="http://127.0.0.1/api/table.xml"
set parameter="content=sensors&columns=status&username=wey&passhash=2476365312"
set com=COM4
set baud=9600
set parity=n
set data=8

::Read XML
curl.exe --data %parameter% %url% > %temp%\tmp.xml

::Init COM Port
mode %com% BAUD=%baud% PARITY=%parity% DATA=%data%

::Check for warnings and error in xml
findstr ">4< >5<" %temp%\tmp.xml
if errorlevel 1 goto noerror
goto Check_for_warnings_in_xml

:Check_for_warnings_in_xml
findstr /C:">5<" %temp%\tmp.xml
if errorlevel 1 goto warning
goto error

:warning
start "" "C:/curl/curl.exe" -d "off" http://10.20.0.20/api/prtg_alarm
start "" "C:/curl/curl.exe" -d "on" http://10.20.0.20/api/prtg_warning
echo Warning found
echo warning_found > %com%
goto end

:error
start "" "C:/curl/curl.exe" -d "off" http://10.20.0.20/api/prtg_warning
start "" "C:/curl/curl.exe" -d "on" http://10.20.0.20/api/prtg_alarm
echo Error found
echo error_found > %com%
goto end

:noerror
start "" "C:/curl/curl.exe" -d "off" http://10.20.0.20/api/prtg_alarm
start "" "C:/curl/curl.exe" -d "off" http://10.20.0.20/api/prtg_warning
echo No error found
echo no_error > %com%
goto end

:end
del %temp%\tmp.xml>nul 2>&1
endlocal
exit
```