# Mock a failure and success command calls in batch for testing purposes

Tags: batch

Is there any command I can use in place of `<command>`, with some argument in place of `<argument_that_fails>` and `<argument_that_succeed>`, such that `echo %IS_SUCCESS%` would print `FALSE` on the first script, and `TRUE` on the second script?

```
set IS_SUCCESS=FALSE
<command><argument_that_fails> && set IS_SUCCESS=TRUE
echo %IS_SUCCESS%
```

```
set IS_SUCCESS=FALSE
<command><argument_that_succeed> && set IS_SUCCESS=TRUE
echo %IS_SUCCESS%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one will succeed:

`type filethatexists.txt>nul &&...`

This one will fail:

`type filethatdoesntexist.txt>nul &&...`

Answer (score 0):

```all-bat
set IS_SUCCESS=FALSE
[command] [argument_that_fails] && set IS_SUCCESS=TRUE
echo %IS_SUCCESS%

set IS_SUCCESS=FALSE
[command] [argument_that_succeed]  && set IS_SUCCESS=TRUE
echo %IS_SUCCESS%
```

Your commands bring me the feeling that you are looking for control over the actions conditioned to the results of the executions, the same as return 0 for success and return non 0 for eventual failure.

What in **[batch](/questions/tagged/batch)**/**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** can be obtained using the operators, who took actions based on the return of successful executions or not:

```all-bat
set "IS_SUCCESS="
[command] [argument] && set "IS_SUCCESS=TRUE" || set "IS_SUCCESS=FALSE"
echo\%IS_SUCCESS%
```

It is also possible to use conditioned executions within blocks

```all-bat
[command] [argument] && (execute because return 0) || (execute because return non 0)
```

```all-bat
set "IS_SUCCESS="
[command] [argument] && ( 

set "IS_SUCCESS=TRUE"
echo\ [command] [argument] succeed ) || (

set "IS_SUCCESS=FALSE" 
echo\ [command] [argument] fails )

echo\%IS_SUCCESS%
```

For use with blocks, several configurations/layout/shapes are possible, with multiple lines, which will depend on the number of commands conditioned to the pertinent actions.

But it can also be used/necessary (depends on your code) to also use these operators within the execution blocks of the operator already in use, as you can see in this **[answer](https://superuser.com/a/1559545/969781)**:

```all-bat
2>nul findstr "\<4\>" "%tmp%\tmp.xml" >nul && (
2>nul findstr "\<5\>" "%tmp%\tmp.xml" >nul && (
goto error ) || goto warning ) || goto noerror
```

What is worth noting in this example above is that, in addition to the multiple use of operators inside and outside blocks, the output command redirectors are in use suppressing /omitting any error messages, warnings or the effective normal exit of the successful command:

[image]

Another thing that is possible to do in actions of command execution tests, is the test for multiple executions, where what matters is to assume an x ​​or y action in case an entire block of commands was successful or not:

```all-bat
(dir /b ,0 & type . <nul) && echo\All execution zOk! || echo\Something really wrong here!
```

- Command outputs:

```all-bat
File Not Found
Access is denied.
Something really wrong here!
```

Using `2>nul` for suppressing any `error` messages and/or `warnings`

```all-bat
>2nul (dir /b ,0 & type . <nul) && echo\All execution zOk! || echo\Something really wrong here!
```

- Command output:

```all-bat
Something really wrong here!
```

---

- Answering your question, my suggest for succeed case would be:

```all-bat
>2nul (dir /b , & type nul <nul) && echo\All execution zOk! || echo\Something really wrong
```

- Command output:

```all-bat
All execution zOk!
```

- Answering your question, my suggest for fail case would be:

```all-bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "IS_SUCCESS=" & 2>nul dir /b , >nul  && ( set "IS_SUCCESS=TRUE"
echo\ dir /b , succeed ) || ( set "IS_SUCCESS=FALSE" & echo\ dir /b , fails )

echo\%IS_SUCCESS%

endlocal
```

- Command output:

```all-bat
TRUE
```

- Answering your question, my suggest for fail case would be:

```all-bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "IS_SUCCESS=" & 2>nul dir /b ,0 >nul  && ( set "IS_SUCCESS=TRUE"
echo\ dir /b , succeed ) || ( set "IS_SUCCESS=FALSE" & echo\ dir /b , fails )

echo\%IS_SUCCESS%

endlocal
```

- Command output:

```all-bat
FALSE
```

- Some command that fail:

```all-bat
rd .
cd :
dir /,
dir ,0
type .
cd nul
set /a
tree nul
move con
```

- About `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, consider using it in situations involving operators, blocks, multiple `for` lopping

  - ```all-bat
    By default expansion will happen just once, before each line is executed.
    The !delayed! expansion is performed each time the line is executed, or for
    each loop in a FOR looping command.
    Note: Source linked to ss64.com
    ```
- About the use of double quotes in variables (`set "_varible=values"`) well,  let's say that some years ago I found peace within myself just by using them...

---

- Some further reading:

[√] **[Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

[√] **[Display & Redirect Output](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php)**

[√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

[√] **[EnableExpansion|DelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)**